# What is a JavaScript 'Call' and how does it relate to efficiency?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, query-optimization

I'm doing some testing and optimizing on a JavaScript function I made.  I notice that the add-on I'm using in Firefox (FireUnit) gives a return of the number of calls done during the profiling time.  Is this the number of http calls made by the script?

Also, can you outline/discuss/grade/explain as to how many calls is considered within a good range?  Maybe by giving examples or commonly-used JavaScript functions such as drop-down menus, hide/show images, image slideshow functionality, etc...

Does a call represent any measure of 'work' or merely the iterations performed?

Comment: I think calls mean function calls. How many time a particular function was called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, a call is the amount of times a function has been invoked.

```
function foo() {

};

foo();
foo();
```

The function foo has been called/ invoked **twice** in the above example.

There is no answer for "what is a good range of calls". A function like `jQuery` will most likely be called a large number of times per page, whereas you would expect a function like `init()` to be called only once.

A better representation of the efficiency of your functions is their execution time; this records the amount of time taken for the function to execute (almost always recorded in milliseconds). Functions with long execution times could be optimized to lower their execution time and improve the efficiency of your program.

To best spend you time, you could combine the two statistics (call count and execution time), and look at optimizing the functions that are called a large number of times, and have longer execution times.

Comment: His subquestion about how many questions is considered good is what? I suppose it depends on the function itself. Calls only tell how much have you improved one function's execution... Calls on their own mean hardly anything until the number becomes extremely low.

Comment: Does the call itself represent any real 'cost'?  Or alternatively, does it depend on the functions being called?

Comment: @Eric: “Does the call itself represent any real 'cost'?” — well, when you call a function, all the code in it will run. If some of that code doesn’t need to run, then that’s a “cost” in the sense that unnecessary work is being done.

Comment: Additionally, the pure number of calls which a piece of Javascript code makes doesn't really have much bearing on how 'good' or 'bad' that code is. Some code might make 3 method calls but be designed poorly and as such run very inefficiently; some other code might make thousands of method calls but be very efficient.

Comment: @Eric: I've expanded my answer. Hope it makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

The number of calls means how many times a given function was run or invoked or executed. There is no good range in the number of calls. This number gives you two most important informations:

First, if some function is called only once and some other function is called 100 times then every optimization in the latter is 100 times more important than in the former. It is often a waste of time to optimize a function called only once, but if a function is called a lot of times then it may be important to see if it is not too slow.

The second thing you can see from the number of function calls is that if some function is called hundreds of times when in fact it always has the same result then it might mean that you are calling it inside a loop when calling it once and storing the value in a variable might be sufficient.

For example this would call the expensiveFunction 1000 times:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    array[i] = i + expensiveFunction();
}
```

While this would call it only once:

```
value = expensiveFunction();
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    array[i] = i + value;
}
```

Seeing that some of your functions was called a lot of times might be a hint that you have some code similar to that example. Of course you can't cache the value every time but sometimes you do and knowing the number of function calls can be useful.